# Error "Notice: Trying to get property 'fetch_row' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion3.php on line 28"

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, xampp

Estudio diseño y me dejaron de tarea programar en php una base de datos, el problema es que me sale

> "Notice: Trying to get property 'fetch_row' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion3.php on line 28"  cuando lo abro en
>   el navegador. Se refiere a la línea que tiene
>   "$filas=$resultado->fetch_row;"

No sé cómo solucionarlo pues según el formato así tiene que ser, yo sólo cambié la información de la base de datos.
El código completo es éste:

```
<?php

$myconexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "auto_veloz","3306");
if ($myconexion->connect_error) {
    die("Error en la conexión". $myconexion->connect_error);
}
else{
    echo " Se ha establecido la conexión con éxito...". $myconexion->host_info ."<br><br>" ;
}

?>


<html>
 <head>
  <title>Ejemplo 2 de conexión</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#D30083" style="color='#FFFFFF'";><td>Nombre</td><td>Número de empleado</td></tr>

<?php

    $resultado=$myconexion->query("select nombre,nempleado from auto_veloz");

    $filas=$resultado->fetch_row;
    if ($filas >=1){

       while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onmouseover="this.style.background='#FFFFFF';" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFFFFF';">
       <td> <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?> </td>
       <td> <?php echo $fila['nempleado']; ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php
       }
    }
?>

    </table>
 </body>
</html>


<?php

$myconexion->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Hay varios errores en tu código:

1. La conexión no debería ser gestionada más arriba del encabezado de la página, sino en el `body`. No sé por qué lo has hecho así.
2. Estás mezclando dos métodos `fetch`, lo cual es un error. Cuando se hace una consulta con `mysqli`, es devuelto un recurso que apunta a los datos, y los métodos `fetch` sirven generalmente para leer ese recurso línea por línea. Cada vez que aplicas un método `fetch` el recurso se mueve una fila. En tu caso, si es que funciona, el `fetch_assoc()` comenzaría en la 2ª fila de datos, porque `fetch_row` habría movido el puntero una fila.
3. Además, usas `fetch_row` como si fuera una propiedad (sin paréntesis), cuando en realidad es un método. La propiedad para saber la cantidad de filas de un conjunto de resultados es [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Dicho todo esto, pasemos a corregir el código:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Ejemplo 2 de conexión</title>
 </head>

 <body>

    <?php
    $myconexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "auto_veloz","3306");
    if ($myconexion->connect_error) {
        die("Error en la conexión". $myconexion->connect_error);
    }
    else{
        echo " Se ha establecido la conexión con éxito...". $myconexion->host_info ."<br><br>" ;

        $resultado=$myconexion->query("select nombre,nempleado from auto_veloz");
        if ($resultado) {
            $filas=$resultado->num_rows;
            if ($filas >=1){
        ?>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#D30083" style="color='#FFFFFF'";><td>Nombre</td><td>Número de empleado</td></tr>
        <?php
                while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onmouseover="this.style.background='#FFFFFF';" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFFFFF';">
                        <td> <?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $fila['nempleado']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
        <?php
                }
        ?>
            </table>
        <?php

            }
        } else {
            echo "Error: ".$myconexion->error;
        }
        $myconexion->close();
    }
    ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

He puesto cada cosa en su sitio (la conexión, la apertura y cierre de `table`, etc), he usado los métodos/propiedades adecuadas y he añadido un control de errores sobre los resultados para informar adecuadamente sobre un eventual error en ese sentido.

Espero te sirva.